# Select half of the dataframe given values in one column

Tags: r, select, subset, rows

I want to select half of the dataframe given values in one of the columns. In other words, from the dataframe given below I need to extract half of rows given values in column Y:

```
DF:
 id1  column Y   value
9830     A         6 
7609     A         0 
9925     B         0 
9922     B         5 
9916     B         6
9917     B         8 
9914     C         2
9914     C         7
9914     C         7
9914     C         2
9914     C         9
```

New data frame should look like this:

```
  NEW DF:
     id1  column Y   value
    9830     A         6 
    9925     B         0 
    9922     B         5 
    9914     C         2
    9914     C         7
```

Also, it would be helpful to know solution for selecting random half of all rows datefram DF given column Y (e.g. not selecting first 50%).

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the first half of each group of rows with the same value for `column Y` where for odd number of rows we round down, we can use `filter` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(`column Y`) %>% filter(row_number() <= floor(n()/2))
##Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
##Groups: column Y [3]
##
##    id1 column Y laclen
##  <int>   <fctr>  <int>
##1  9830        A      6
##2  9925        B      0
##3  9922        B      5
##4  9914        C      2
##5  9914        C      7
```

We first `group_by` `column Y` (note the back quotes since the column name contains space) and then use `filter` to keep only the rows for which the `row_number` is less than or equal to the total number of rows given by `n()` for the group divided by `2` (and rounded down with `floor`).

---

To select a random 50% of the rows in each group, use `sample` to generate the row numbers to keep and `%in%` to match those to keep:

```
set.seed(123)
result <- df %>% group_by(`column Y`) %>% filter(row_number() %in% sample(seq_len(n()),floor(n()/2)))
##Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
##Groups: column Y [3]
##
##    id1 column Y laclen
##  <int>   <fctr>  <int>
##1  9830        A      6
##2  9922        B      5
##3  9917        B      8
##4  9914        C      2
##5  9914        C      9
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! And do you know how to select random 50% of rows and not only first 50%?